# How to replace form_for with form_with for sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby-on-Rails. Currently, in my login form I have

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
```

I want to replace form_for with form_with. I have tried:

```
<%= form_with :session, url: login_path do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= form_with model: :session, url: login_path do |f| %>
```

But in both cases I get errors in the session controller.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please attached your complete errors.

Comment: What does your sessions controller look like?

Comment: I did as Anees Muhammed said and it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `scope` to make it work

```
<%= form_with scope: :session, url: login_path do |form| %>
```